# How to understand Gd eating?

Tags: theology, avodah-zarah, eating, vaeschanan

How does our tradition understand the mention in [Devarim 4:28](http://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.4.28?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all) of our Gd eating? In what respects does Gd "eat"?

> וַעֲבַדְתֶּם־שָׁ֣ם אֱלֹהִ֔ים מַעֲשֵׂ֖ה יְדֵ֣י אָדָ֑ם עֵ֣ץ וָאֶ֔בֶן
>   אֲשֶׁ֤ר לֹֽא־יִרְאוּן֙ וְלֹ֣א יִשְׁמְע֔וּן וְלֹ֥א יֹֽאכְל֖וּן וְלֹ֥א
>   יְרִיחֻֽן
>
> And there ye shall serve gods, the work of men’s hands, wood and
>   stone, which neither see, nor hear, nor eat, nor smell.

A critique of specific limitations of other gods clearly implies that our Gd does not have those limitations. (At least, as I read it.)

Comment: Do you mean [Devarim 4:28](http://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.4.28?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all)? Is your suggestion that because that verse lists various things that idols don't do, those must be things that God does do? If so, I'd suggest [edit]ing in support for that deduction, since it seems pretty weak at face value.

Comment: The statement means that idols are inert objects that cannot affect the world in the way that their "claimed being" would normally do so. This does not imply that Hashem has anthropomorphic characteristics.

Comment: @sabbahillel  A critique of specific limitations of other gods clearly implies that our Gd does not have those limitations.  (At least, it seems I read it.)

Comment: If you don't agree with my edits to your post, please [edit] yourself to fix. I just corrected the link to the verse you cited, quoted it, and copied your comment into the actual question so that the basis of your question appears more clearly. cc @IsaacMoses

Comment: Correct, however not having limitations does not mean that Hashem walks, talks, sees, eats or smells **in the physical sense**. On the other hand the idols are **supposed** to do these things (literally) and they (as inert pieces of matter) cannot (rather than do not). Thus the statement is a matter of the idols not even being able to act in the limited way that humans and animals do.

Comment: "A critique of specific limitations of other gods clearly implies that our Gd does not have those limitations". This seems to be a *kal vachomer* but in the wrong direction. I think you can only infer that b/c G-d is ominpotent and has no limits, everything else does have limits, which, I think is what the verse is stating. Not the other way around. Also, the concept of eating and smelling is used to indicate that people ascribed humanistic qualities to these idols, which does NOT apply to G-d, since he is not human, and wasn't fashioned by humans as idols are.

Answer (score 1):

The same question can be asked of G-d smelling (by korbanos), speaking, (and in a similar way knowing, regretting). 
We first have to discuss what are these things in a conceptual sense. What is eating? You take something in and it gives you energy. So if learning increases your intellectual ability, then learning can be said to be eating because you took in the information and it gave you additional ability to think. (there is some source for torah being called food in this sense but it doesn't occur to me at the moment where. now in reference to G-d things get tricky because does G-d lack that he needs something extra? In kabbalah there are various ways G-d reveals himself and being that G-d wants the worlds to work in a logical way. Therefore these revelations are limited in various ways and once you have limitation you have lack and once you have lack you need to "eat" to make up for that lack.